# Syncfusion grid font on windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, syncfusion

It seems to be a problem for me to set GridGroupingControl's font in windows XP.

Here is the code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.autoLabel1.Font = new Font(Fonts.GetFontFamily(), 10f);
            this.normalLabel.Font = new Font(Fonts.GetFontFamily(), 10f);
            this.gridGroupingControl1.Font = new Font(Fonts.GetFontFamily(), 10f);
        }
    }

public static class Fonts
    {
        private static PrivateFontCollection pfc;

        public static System.Drawing.FontFamily GetFontFamily()
        {

            try
            {
                if (pfc == null)
                {
                    pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_Bold);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_BoldItalic);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_ExtraBold);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_ExtraBoldItalic);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_Italic);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_Light);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_LightItalic);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_Regular);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_Semibold);
                    AddMemoryFont(Properties.Resources.OpenSans_SemiboldItalic);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return pfc.Families.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr AddFontMemResourceEx(IntPtr pbFont, uint cbFont, IntPtr pdv, [In] ref uint pcFonts);


        private static void AddMemoryFont(byte[] fontResource)
        {
            try
            {
                IntPtr p;
                uint c = 0;

                p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontResource.Length);
                Marshal.Copy(fontResource, 0, p, fontResource.Length);
                AddFontMemResourceEx(p, (uint)fontResource.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref c);
                pfc.AddMemoryFont(p, fontResource.Length);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(p);

                p = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this application on windows7 there is no problem with displaying correct font in grid but when the same application is being run at windows XP the font in grid is actually default (MS Sans).

EDIT: When I use to set this font to other syncfusion controls it's working fine.

How to fix his problem? Is there actually any way to do this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [Still using XP?](https://imgflip.com/i/17s5is) By the way, I'm not sure you want to `throw ex;`

Comment: There is nothing useful in your comment. Some customers are still using this OS. By the way, `throw ex;` doesn't matter here

Comment: ask the same at support@syncfusion.com

Comment: `throw ex;` is just a general advice, since it clear the `innerException`. And what's the point of life if you can't spend a bit of your time to laugh?

Comment: Already asked support@syncfusion.com. No response